# MacBook Air 2020 won't display more than 1 external monitor at a time

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, hdmi

I have 2020 M1 MBA, with 2 USB-C ports.

My Dell monitor connects with USB-C, but I have another Acer monitor with HDMI. When I connect my Acer display to my Mac to the second port, via HDMI-to-USB-C adapter, the Dell monitor disconnects, and it only shows the Acer monitor. Doing this in reverse order will cause only the Dell to display and not the Acer.

My Macbook is plugged in and getting power, and all my cables are working.
Using the "detect displays" button in the system settings does nothing.
Going in and out of sleep mode does nothing.
Restarting does nothing.

What is causing my MacBook Air to not display both monitors at the same time?

Comment: I suggest you read this documentation : https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/connect-an-external-display-mchl7c7ebe08/mac

Comment: I see it says "For Mac computers with Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C): You can connect a single display to each port." which is what I'm doing. I notice above, it says Macs with M1s can only display one monitor, but these statements seem to be at odds with each other, since the implication is M1 models only have 1 port available, but mine has 2 thunderbolt ports available.

Comment: The 2020 Airs are one external display only.

Comment: Bummer. I wonder what the justification is for this limitation.

Comment: Airs have always been limited. This one I would imagine is for thermal reasons. No fans, overheat a distinct possibility.

Comment: Did you try to connect one by USBC and one by HDMI